# simple salesforce update on custom field

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

Is it possible to update an account on salesforce using an external custom field? 
I've tried `sf.Account.Update("Custom_Field__c:{}.format(field), data)` and I cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late, but in case somebody else stumbles on this:

The answer is yes, however your code is formatted incorrectly.

The update method that you're asking about is actually lower-case, it typically takes two arguments to evaluate correctly, a valid SF Id as a string, and the data you want to update with as a dictionary. So to fix what's going on in your question it would look like:

```
sf.Account.update("15characterIdoftheAccount", {"Custom_Field__c:{}.format(thevalueyouwanttoshowupinSF)})
```